# XOR Cipher in Python: Two Methods With Two Results?

Tags: python, encryption, xor

Recently, I have been exploring the XOR cipher in Python.  I have two 'working' methods:

```
def XORcipher(plaintext, key):
    output = ""
    for character in plaintext:
        for letter in key:
            character = chr(ord(character) ^ ord(letter))
        output += character
    return output
```

and

```
def XORcipher2(plaintext, key):
    from itertools import izip, cycle
    return ''.join(chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x,y) in izip(plaintext, cycle(key)))
```

Both of these are able to encrypt a given string and decrypt back.  What I can't seem to understand is why they give different results.

Using `23` as my key:

> XORcipher = 
>       Usx!un!dobsxqu!uihr!ldrr`fd!trhof!YNS!dobsxquhno/

and

> XORcipher2 = 
>       fAKF\V\P@JBGGZZA_VA@STWG@[]Uj|`W]QAKCFZ]]

If anyone could help me better understand these results, I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

For the first function, the last character in the key is ALWAYS used. This is because it assigns to `character` in the for-loop every time you iterate, and throws away the last character until you iterate to the end.

For the second one, take plaintext `"abc"` and key `"42"`. `"a"` is encrypted with `"4"`. `"b"` with `"2"` and `"c"` with `"4"` again as you used `cycle()` so it goes back to the beginning.

With the first function, it is `"a"` with `"2"`, `"b"` with `"2"` and `"c"` with `"2"`.

To expand the list comprehension, it would be this:

```
from itertools import izip, cycle
def list_comp(plaintext, key):
    return ''.join(chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x,y) in izip(plaintext, cycle(key)))

def not_list_comp(plaintext, key):
    temp = []
    for x, y in izip(plaintext, cycle(key)):
        temp.append(chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)))
    return ''.join(temp)
```

Comment: "...every time you iterate, and throw away the last character..." - It does't throws away, instead it repeatedly xor the result with each char in the key: `character = chr(ord(character) ^ ord(letter))`.

Comment: @PauloScardine Yeah, I didn't look at the name of the variable. I just assumed it was something different. In this case, the previous value of `character` is not accessible again. That's what I mean by "throw away".

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, for each letter of the plaintext, you are performing a xor with each character of the key. If you do `XORcipher2('foo', 'bar')` the sequence is:

```
chr(ord('f') ^ ord('b'))     # '\x04'
chr(ord('\x04') ^ ord('a'))  # ´e´
chr(ord('e') ^ ord('r'))     # '\x17'
output += '\x17'
chr(ord('o') ^ ord('b'))     # '\r'
chr(ord('\r') ^ ord('a'))    # 'e'
chr(ord('l') ^ ord('r'))     # '\x1e'
output += '\x1e'
chr(ord('o') ^ ord('b'))
chr(ord('\r') ^ ord('a'))
chr(ord('l') ^ ord('r'))
output += '\x1e'
```

Probably what you really want is (assuming you want an alternative to the algorithm using `itertools`):

```
def XORcipher(plaintext, key):
    output = ""
    for i, character in enumerate(plaintext):
        output += chr(ord(character) ^ ord(key[i % len(key)]))
    return output
```

Proof:

```
>>> XORcipher('foo', 'bar')
'\x04\x0e\x1d'
>>> XORcipher2('foo', 'bar')
'\x04\x0e\x1d'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Paulo!  I like this solution a lot.  For some reason. the itertools version is easier for me to remember.  Is there a difference between the two in performance?  Is there a 'cost' to importing modules as opposed to doing it natively?

Comment: Itertools is a built-in module, so it should be OK. I have not checked the sources but I suspect most of it is just syntax sugar for some of the tricks used in this answer like using `alist[i % len(alist)]` instead of `itertools.cycle`. I guess you can make the plain python perform better at the cost of some legibility but in a higher level language like Python performance can be very counter-intuitive - more than one time I had to bite my tongue so always profile.

Comment: As a side note, if you really care about performance, the canonical solution  in cpython is to re-implement critical bits in C/C++ and interface using its C interface or CFFI. It is quite easy to make a wrapper around a native library/DLL.